# Is it possible to reference and run a PowerShell function in VS code containing internal functions from a module?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

So I am writing a function for a module.
This function calls internal logging functions.
Is it possible for me to run my script within VS code using F5 test?
Or do I just have to run it from an external ps window?

Comment: [Good guide on debugging PowerShell code in vscode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/debugging-powershell-script-in-visual-studio-code-part-1/)

Comment: While possible through "launch.json", I would write a Pester test for the function. Pester Test Explorer module for VSCode gives you the ability to launch a test from VSCode and also gives you nice "debug" links directly over the test function, within the editor window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me when it comes to modules.

I have in VSCode a TestMyModule.ps1 script with Import-Module pointing to the module, seldom do I have 'Using Module' because I agree with Stéphane van Gulick:
https://stephanevg.github.io/powershell/class/module/DATA-How-To-Write-powershell-Modules-with-classes/

I have both the module, and the TestMyModule script, open in VSCode at the same time.  Making changes in the module, and switching to the TestMyModule script before pressing F5, has become natural and I do it without thinking.

Most everything in a module (other than classes), once imported, is available UNLESS you are using any Export-ModuleMember statements in the module, then nothing is available except those things explicitly offered by the Export-ModuleMember statements.

So, if you are using Export-ModuleMember, then you will have to include one that makes your function available.  BUT, if you don't want those functions available in the end product, you will have to remember to remove them later.

Before the Import-Module statement, I normally have:

```
Get-Module | Remove-Module
```

to ensure I'm not testing the old version of the module still in memory.

But another approach in VSCode is to always do a Ctrl+Shift+P -> "PowerShell: Restart Current Session" before each test.

Yet another way is to ensure the module is reloaded is to configure VSCode to start a new terminal each time you debug.  I'm thinking its the "Debugging: Create Temporary Integrated Console" under the PowerShell Configuration in settings that does this - but not sure.  What I do know is if you get that turned on, F5 changes from nearly instant to a wait of around 4 or 5 seconds.

Also, I don't believe there is any way to test the methods in a class in a module other than creating an instance of the class and calling the method.

All that being said, I agree with zett42 that Pester is a good tool to use.  And, I should add, I often do little of what I just described, but instead I thoroughly test functions in a different ps1 script.  Only after the function is working as expected, do I copy it to the module.